# How to hash email using the SHA-256 algorithm in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm installing a Pinterest tracking code and need to hash a email using SHA-256.

**From Pinterest Docs:**

Enhanced Match may also be used with the img tag. However, partners that use the img tag will need to format and hash  themselves. Specifically,  will need to be lower-cased and have all whitespace removed. They will then need to be hashed using the SHA-256 algorithm.

The formatted and hashed  should be added to every Pinterest tag img tag URL on your page using the "&pd[em]=" parameter. The em parameter should be added to both the base code and the event code img tags.

For example:

```
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt=""
src="https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?tid=<YOUR_TAG_ID>&event=<EVENT_NAME>&pd[em]=<hashed_email_address>&noscript=1" />
</noscript>
```

My code so far:

```
    <?php
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { 
           $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
           $CustomerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
        }
    ?>


    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt=""
  src="https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?tid=<?php echo $id ?>&pd[em]=<?php echo $CustomerEmail ?>&noscript=1" />
```

It seems I read Magento has this built-in not sure.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found the answer here: [How to use sha256 in php5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752477/how-to-use-sha256-in-php5-3-0)

My new code:

```
<?php 
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
   $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
   $CustomerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
}
$pageIdentifier = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
?>
<script>
!function(e){if(!window.pintrk){window.pintrk = function () {
window.pintrk.queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))};var
      n=window.pintrk;n.queue=[],n.version="3.0";var
      t=document.createElement("script");t.async=!0,t.src=e;var
      r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      r.parentNode.insertBefore(t,r)}}("https://s.pinimg.com/ct/core.js");
pintrk('load', '<?php echo $id ?>', {em: '<?php echo $CustomerEmail ?>'});
pintrk('page');
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt=""
src="https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?tid=<?php echo $id ?>&event=<?php echo $pageIdentifier ?>&pd[em]=<?php echo hash('sha256', $CustomerEmail); ?>=1" />
</noscript>
```

I'm getting good :)

Comment: Where did you put this code? In what file?